# Auto sorting in horizontal html table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm trying to create a horizontal table which can be sorted automatically.
e.g.

```
           |Country 1|Country2|
Population |    12134|  232312|
GPD        |       23|      34|
```

I want to sort by Population or GPD. I used to use tablesorter for table problems but I can't find any thing for this.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use list.js

http://listjs.com/

has good support for sorting tables. See if it fulfills your needs.

Comment: thanks. This is what i need, but unfortunately, in the previous version we used <table> too much. changing to <li> would be a real challenge.